i want to write code for checking whether for loop.index is divisible by 10 or not in shopify
enter image description here
when I write this code       {% if forloop.index % 10 == 0 %}
why it is showing error? Please Help
 {% if forloop.index % 10 == 0 %}
        <div class="banner">
            <p>This is a banner displayed after every 10 products!</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

I've tried this code but it is not working
Please help

This question is similar to: Using modulo on forloop.index in Jekyll Liquid. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't know much about shopify, but have you tried running the code like this?
{% assign remainder = forloop.index | modulo:10 %}

    {% if remainder == 0 %}
        <div class="banner">
            <p>This is a banner displayed after every 10 products!</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

